# Best practice to connect objects between them in ruby

Tags: ruby

I cannot manage to find a nice way to implement the rails behavior of objects navigation rails has in a pure ruby script.

Say I have an object of class Parent, with an accessor to an Array of objects of class Child, I'd like, when I manipulate a Child object, to be able to get the Parent easily, like that :

```
class Parent
  attr_accessor :children

  def initialize
    @children = Array.new
  end
end

class Child
end

parent = Parent.new
first_child = Child.new
second_child = Child.new
parent.children << [ first_child, second_child ]

a_child = parent.children.first

get_parent_from_child = a.child.parent
```

The part I'm interested in is, of course, the last line in which I attempt to get the "parent" object from one of its children.

How could I implement it easily and cleanly ?

I was thinking of adding an accessor to the child object, but I'm not sure how to make sure this value is set everytime I attach a child object to a parent object.

Is there an easy and clean way of doing that in ruby ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the `has_many` behavior from Rails by using a custom container class, like Rails does.

```
class Parent
  attr_reader :children

  def initialize
    @children = ChildCollection.new(self)
  end
end

class Child
  attr_accessor :parent
end

class ChildCollection
  def initialize parent
    @children = []
    @parent = parent
  end

  def new
    child = Child.new
    child.parent = @parent
    @children << child
    child
  end

  def << child
    child.parent = @parent
    @children << child
    self
  end
end
```

And some example code to add children to the parent:

```
parent = Parent.new
child1 = parent.children.new
child2 = Child.new
child3 = Child.new
parent.children << child2 << child3

puts "Parent is: #{parent.object_id}"
puts "Child1's parent is: #{child1.parent.object_id}"
puts "Child2's parent is: #{child2.parent.object_id}"
puts "Child3's parent is: #{child3.parent.object_id}"
```

You may want to throw on some other helpful methods like `remove` and `each` (so you can have `ChildCollection` include the `Enumerable` module and get all the cool stuff that comes with that) but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: In the `Parent` class I used `attr_reader :children` instead of `attr_accessor` because we need to make sure that our container contains a reference to the proper parent object.  We are still free to add and remove children from the collection.

Comment: Oh yes, that looks like what I was looking for. I'll try to implement it on monday in my project.
Thanks, Ian.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to fully expose your `children` you know, there's nothing wrong with fully controlling access to your data.

```
class Parent
  def initialize
    @children = [ ]
  end

  # You get a shallow copy of the children, you can
  # change the individual children but not the tree
  # structure.
  def children
    @children.dup
  end

  # We take ownership of the children when you add them.
  def add_children(*kids)
    kids.each { |k| k.parent = self }
    @children += kids
  end

  def remove_children(&block)
    @children.delete_if(&block)
  end
end

# This would probably have some sort of payload and
# a sensible "==" implementation.
class Child
  attr_reader :parent
  def parent=(p)
    raise StandardError => 'Not allowed to change parents!' if @parent
    @parent = p
  end
end
```

Then `child.parent` works fine and if you want to remove children you'd tell the parent which ones to remove:

```
# Remove the children with even payloads.
parent.remove_children { |c| c.payload % 2 == 0 }

# Remove the children with odd payloads and copy them.
odds = [ ]
parent.remove_children do |c|
  kill_it = c.payload % 2 != 0
  odds << Child.new(c.payload) if(kill_it)
  kill_it
end
```

Comment: Nice upgrade to ckruse's answer, but I prefer Ian's as it's more what I was looking for.
Thanks a lot for your help, mu (is too short), hehe, I like your name.

Comment: @Baramin: No worries, having several options is a good thing as is going with what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Write an own accessor for children in the class Parent in which you set a parent attribute for each child added to the array. Do the reverse when removing children from the array. This is how I would do it.

Comment: Ok. I could do that indeed, add a add_child and delete_child to the parent object.
I'll start implementing it this way for now, and if noone else has a better solution, will validate your answer.
I sure would prefer a way that would allow things like new_child = parent.children.new() for example.

Comment: You can do this, too. Derive a class from array and implement a method new_child(), which sets the property `parent` and after that calls `self << new_child`.